# JavaScript код (обратный отчет) сбрасывается при обновлении - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, таймер

Здравствуйте. Есть код

```
var timer,
    num = 5,
    output = $('#ress');

function changeNum(){
    output.text(num--);
    //каждый раз задержка будет на 100ms больше
    if(num >= 1) setTimeout(changeNum,10000+(5-num)*15000);
}
setTimeout(changeNum,500);
```

-

Этот код 5 доводит до 1. Нужно сделать так, чтобы отчет сохранился у клиента, чтобы при обновлении страницы отчет продолжался. Я отсталый в этом, по этому готовый скрипт будет куда кстати. Спасибо

Прекрасно будет, если бы отчет сбрасывался через часа два-три

Comment: Используйте cookie

Comment: уже несколько часов роюсь и никак не могу понять как сделать

Comment: Это поможет https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Comment: Не используйте куки, используйте localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Данные между обновлениями страницы нужно где-то хранить, можно хранить их в localStorage.

Сохраним дату старта и будем рассчитывать количество пройденного времени.

```
function start(N) {
  var nextDiff;
  if (!localStorage.counter) {
    localStorage.counter = JSON.stringify({start: Date.now(), n: N});
  }
  var counter = JSON.parse(localStorage.counter);
  console.log(counter);
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var current = counter.n;
    var diff = Date.now() - counter.start;
    console.log(diff);
    if (diff > 5000+(N-current)*5000) { // 5s, 10, 15s, 20s, 25s ...
      if (!(--counter.n)) {
        console.log('Finished!');
        clearInterval(interval);
        delete localStorage.counter;
        return;
      }
      counter.start = Date.now();
      console.log('decremented!', counter);

      localStorage.counter = JSON.stringify(counter);
    }
  }, 1e3);
}

start(5);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj9m7y1k/)

Comment: не выходит, руки кривые